# How can I use multiple JetBrains IDEs on same project without annoying pop-ups when switching between them?

Tags: phpstorm, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I have a project that uses both PHP and Python, and I would like to use JetBrains IDEs (in this case PhpStorm and PyCharm) to work with both languages.

However when I open the project using both IDEs concurrently I get a pop up whenever I switch from one to the other, as the newly focused IDE detects metadata that has been written to the project directory by the other IDE. I imagine this would be a problem between other combinations of JetBrains IDEs as well.

I have a work around  (I will post in an answer for others to view), but it is somewhat awkward to set up, and I may well be working with other projects that use the same combination of languages.

Is there an easier solution?

Comment: Yes -- use **full** IntelliJ IDEA -- supports all languages via plugins (except AppCode & CLion AFAIK). Other than that -- your solution is the only one (too keep `.idea` subfolder (project settings) in separate places).

Comment: If I can get stuff that I thought was PHPStorm specific (PHP debugging support, phing build tasks etc.) working in IntelliJ, then this solution would be perfect for me as I have a full tools licence. I'd dismissed IntelliJ as solely Java & other JVM languages, previously.

Comment: It should be the same (at least that's what they state .. plus there are many people that use it this way). AFAIK when you launch IntelliJ IDEA for a first time at one of the steps it will ask what other technologies (except java-oriented) you want to activate -- PHP/Python/Ruby should be there on a list (at least this is what I remember when testing it over 1-1.5 years ago). if not -- PHP/Python plugins can be installed manually via standard plugins interface.

Comment: In the past .. when every product had separate release cycle .. the PHP support in IntelliJ could lag behind a bit .. but these days .. with unified versioning and release cycle it's no longer the case. The possible downside -- PhpStorm has simplified project/configuration structure and therefore should be easier to use (for new users for sure). Also, there are some rare cases when something works in PhpStorm but does not in IntelliJ -- but I personally remember only few tickets like this (I've been PhpStorm user since v0.6 or so)

Comment: If you can use IntelliJ -- definitely try it and see how it does for you.

Comment: Yes, this is working very well for me, though had to do a couple of custom things to get it working for my case. Feel free to submit this as an answer, which I will accept.

Answer (score 5):

My current workaround:

Create a new directory separate to the main project directory - using the language specific IDE for the second-most used language in the project, open the new directory as a project, and using the options in `Settings > Project > Project Structure`, add the main project directory as a separate content root.

Whenever needing to work on the parts of the project written in the secondary language, you can now open the new directory instead; this keeps metadata for both IDEs separate.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround which allows for two IDE's to share the same directory without IDE settings conflicts.

JetBrains software allows you to store project settings as either a file based project (`*.iml`), or a directory based project (`.idea`).

To choose file or directory based projects, change the file storage type when opening a project.

Note: [Directory based projects are preferred to file based projects](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206167769-File-based-vs-Directory-based-Projects-Which-way-to-go-?), as they allow for versioning of shared settings. Support for file based projects is deprecated and may be removed.